# Quote from someone else's answer?

Tags: support

I'm new to Stack Overflow and found a question where someone gave an answer that was not wrong in the first place but he missed some detail from the original question. What is now the correct way to react?

Should I add an answer and manually quote the part from the former answer to say my opinion to this? Or this there something else I can do? As far as I see, I'm not able to post comments now - but would this the best way? (So that I simply can't do anything at the moment?)

Edit:
To give a concrete example:
[xHTML: region (div) in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727624/xhtml-region-div-in-a-table)

First answer from Rogier21 says s.th. about divs in td and that is fine. Correct answer - but the question asks for divs that are not in td. This is what I wanted to point out.

Comment: I think in *this* particular case, if that's as simple as your additional info is, just leave it as a comment for the answerer to see, and perhaps edit. Though see answers below, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Links would be helpful.)

Generally speaking, comments are the way to collaborate on improving a question or answer.

If you can't comment you're stuck (for now).

It might be possible to suggest an edit on the answer to address the missed piece or to at least acknowledge that it wasn't addressed without changing the original meaning of the answer, but from what you've said does not appear to be the best way to approach it.

Comment: I'd be extremely careful with editing someone's answer in this way. If you think they missed something in their answer, then you are intending to change (add to) the meaning of their post. Comments would be the first option, with the caveat you note, of course. Still, useful and +1 answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly quote part of the post in question, but you can also add a link to that post if for instance you I wanted to discusses some detail related to [Al Everett's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117878/2509). You can get a valid link for an answer from the gray "link" link at the bottom left of the post display (in the full view).

Comment: I think this is the way to go, if it's too much to just comment on. Be careful you give solid, clear attribution to your source (as you would if it was any other web page), and roll from there.